# Azure functions throwing binding errors on azure portal after upgrading visual studio 2019 to version 16.4

Tags: azure-functions

Production azure functions throwing binding errors for functions which are using SignalR. Issue occurred after deploying new build with Visual Studio 2019(16.4). Previously it was working fine before upgrading VS2019. Unfortunately, to fix this issue I had to re-build the functions projects from Visual Studio 2017 & it worked after deploying VS2017 build.

I have repaired VS2019, Uninstalled & Reinstalled VS2019 Azure Cloud Work Load from VS installer but issue did not resolved. Is there any major change for azure functions in VS2019 - 16.4? how can I fix this issue with VS2019?

Code:

```
[FunctionName("TelemetryProcessor")]
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([IoTHubTrigger(
            "messages/events",
            Connection = "IoTHubConnectionString",
            ConsumerGroup ="device")]EventData message,
            [SignalR(HubName = "TelemetryHub")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
            ExecutionContext context,
            ILogger log)
        {
}
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using the IoTHubTrigger and trying to deploy from VS2019, the 'direction' is left off of the *function.json* file (that is deployed in Azure) under 'bindings'. I have to manually edit and add **"direction": "in"** as a binding for mine to start working after every deploy. You can use the *App Service Editor* to make the edit.

Edit: Also, you have to remove "Run from package file" or you won't be able to make the edit.